# Detect NFC Tags without movement

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am working on Android App using NFC and I want to know if there is any way for transfer data between the tag and the app without any movement.

Let me explain a little.
I pass data to the card when I approach the mobile Tag. But if I want to transfer data again, I have to ward off the mobile phone and bring it back to the Tag.

Is there any way of not having to move the Tag every time I go to pass the data?

Thank you very much!

Regards.

**EDIT**

For example, in my code I have this:

```
 @Override
  protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(WriteTagActivity.this);

    if (_writeMode) {

      if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {

        Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        try {

            if((writeTag(buildNdefMessage(), detectedTag))){

                dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.transfer_alert))
                  .setMessage(getString(R.string.transfer_alert_text)).setCancelable(false)
                  .setIcon(R.drawable.action_about)
                  .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.transfer_alert_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        finish();

                    }

                  }).create().show();

            }else{

                dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.transfer_alert_2))
                  .setMessage(getString(R.string.transfer_alert_text_2)).setCancelable(false)
                  .setIcon(R.drawable.action_about)
                  .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.transfer_alert_button_yes_2), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();

                    }

                  }).setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.transfer_alert_button_no_2), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                         finish();

                     }

                  }).create().show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

      }
    }
  }
```

but if I want to transfer data again to my tag I have to move the mobile phone. How can I transfer data to my Tag without movement and have the tag always with my phone?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What makes you believe that you can only transfer data once for every tap of a tag?

If your tag is an NFC tag (`Ndef`), you can use multiple reads/writes for each tag activation. Similarly if you use any other communication protocol (`IsoDep`, `NfcA`, ...) you can invoke the transceive-method multiple times to exchange multiple commands.

---

**EDIT**

Regarding your example code, you would simply call your `writeTag(...)` method multiple times. Of course this would only make sense if your tag dynamically processes the data.

Comment: Yes but I don´t know how to save detectedTag to execute the writeTag(..) function again.

Comment: You should not save it (though you might want to pass it to a separate thread). Why would you want to? The transactions with the tag should be kept short as its generally assumed that the tag will only be tapped for a short period of time.

Comment: But, if I want to get the tag tapped a long period of time and transfer data every time I click a button? That is not posible?

Comment: It is possible, just store the tag handle and use it as often and as long as you need. However, keep in mind that typically users won't hold the device in perfect position with the tag for a long time (NFC actions should be short).

Comment: And how can I store a TAG type in the device?
Is the first time I work with Android + NFC.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just like you would do with any other object reference. I.e. take `detectedTag` and store it within a scope where you can "later" access it. But remember that for the average use it will be quite tricky to hold the tag in a readable position while pressing buttons on the screen.